# Procedure to export a text file with quote delimiters in row 1 - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv, delimiter

I've got the code below from the microsoft support website [LINK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291296/procedure-to-export-a-text-file-with-both-comma-and-quote-delimiters-i)

The problem is it's working a little too well. I only need the First Row of the columns (basically the table headers) with the "" qualifier. The code below applied the "" to all cells.

I don't know how to make this change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
OM

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport()
   Dim DestFile As String
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim ColumnCount As Integer
   Dim RowCount As Integer

DestFile = "C:\Users\Documents\Data\test.txt"

FileNum = FreeFile()


   On Error Resume Next

   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

   If Err <> 0 Then
  MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
  End
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0

   For RowCount = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count

  For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

     Print #FileNum, """" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
        ColumnCount).Text & """";

     If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
        Print #FileNum,
     Else
        Print #FileNum, ",";
     End If
  Next ColumnCount

 Next RowCount
Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

The data that is being selected in the spreadsheet looks like this below:

```
Date    Close   Open    High    Low
24/04/2008  0.9399  0.9472  0.9484  0.9372
25/04/2008  0.9338  0.9394  0.9423  0.9289
28/04/2008  0.9382  0.9339  0.9405  0.9332
```

And the output I need looks like this:

```
"Date","Close","Open","High","Low"
22/06/2015,21,20.698,21.019,20.575
23/06/2015,20.508,20.96,21.052,20.318
24/06/2015,20.679,20.475,20.709,20.287
```

Output based on @DisplayName's code

```
"Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
7/08/2015 , 3.84145514 , 4.80521243 , 3.4206597 , 3.76001086 , 164329 
8/08/2015 , 3.78715895 , 3.800733 , 0.97017103 , 1.02256685 , 674188
9/08/2015 , 0.95851228 , 1.19425818 , 0.85406678 , 0.95275825 , 532170
```

Would it be possible to remove the spaces between the comma's?

Comment: what's your starting data and what's your code output?

Comment: hey @DisplayName - input/output updated as above. Cheers!

Comment: where do all those output file lines from the 2nd row on come from? they are not from spreadsheet data!

Comment: The numbers are different,yes but it's merely an example of the output format i'm looking for, which is a normal comma delimited file, but with "" in the header row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way could be to create a string variable using vbCrLf where required to start a new line, and then do a single print at the end?  I think this solves the formatting issue:

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport()
    Dim DestFile As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    DestFile = "C:\Users\Documents\Data\test.txt"
    FileNum = FreeFile()

    On Error Resume Next

    Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
        Goto CleanExit
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim PrintString As String

    For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
        PrintString = PrintString & """" & Selection.Cells(1, ColumnCount).Text & """" & IIf(ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count, vbCrLf, ",")
    Next
    For RowCount = 2 To Selection.Rows.Count
        For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
            PrintString = PrintString & Selection.Cells(RowCount, ColumnCount) & IIf(ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count, vbCrLf, ",")
        Next ColumnCount
    Next RowCount
    Print #FileNum, PrintString;

CleanExit:
    Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport()
    Dim DestFile As String
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    DestFile = "C:\Users\Documents\Data\test.txt"
    FileNum = FreeFile()

    On Error Resume Next

    Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
        Goto CleanExit
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
        Print #FileNum, """" & Selection.Cells(1, _
           ColumnCount).Text & """";
        If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
           Print #FileNum,
        Else
           Print #FileNum, ",";
        End If
    Next

    For RowCount = 2 To Selection.Rows.Count
        For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

            If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
               Print #FileNum, Selection.Cells(RowCount, ColumnCount)
            Else
               Print #FileNum, Selection.Cells(RowCount, ColumnCount); ",";
            End If
        Next ColumnCount

    Next RowCount

CleanExit:
    Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: I will certainly mark it as answered. However is it also possible to remove the spaces between the comma's? I've update the output data as per above. Unfortunately the program I'm loading the txt file into doesn't like the spaces :(